# Controller Instance Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am facing a different problem.

According to my code I have a common service where I have written all my functions. I have injected service into 2 different controllers.

Here my **Problem** is I want to call the function in 2nd controller when common service executing under 1st controller. I am passing $scope variable to common service. so when service working under 1st controller $scope variable refers 1st controller only But I want to change the reference of $scope to 2nd controller..

Thanks

Comment: I guess you are going backwards, Why do you want to use scope in services. May be you can try showing you full example and experts here will suggest a better design, more angular way. Just my opinion

Comment: What about using events? $emit/$broadcast. One controller would send out an event that the other would pick up to do its task. With this approach you can pass parameters, therefore you shouldn't need to pass the scope around. In my limited experience with Angular if I find I am passing the scope around a lot I feel I need to review my design and approach. Angular seems to encourage good design practices (IMHO).